# Importing .ser files (Serialized Java Object) into Apache Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a number of `.ser` files generated by a `Java application` of mine.
I'd like them to be read by a `Spark Streaming Java` application, but I can't find the right solution to get this done.

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources) I read some of the guides of the `Spark documentation`.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: If i am able to understand this right you want to read the serde file using java and further processing according to your requirement .

Comment: Those .ser files have data stored. I want to retrieve that data to use it inside my Spark Streaming application.